# Can you build a relativistic clock?

Tags: time, relativity

Is it possible to build a clock that will be immune to relativistic effects on the passage of time? Can a clock exist that will always display the time of the place in which it was set? For instance, if we built the clock on Earth, then put it on a spaceship which accelerated away from the Earth at a significant fraction of the speed of light, the clock would continue to display the time on Earth. To observers on the ship the clock would appear to run faster and faster as the ship accelerated.

Additionally, strong gravitational fields can change the flow of time. If our ship entered orbit around a black hole our clock would still compensate and display the real time on far-away Earth.

The clock must be self-contained. It can't communicate with other clocks or otherwise observe the universe outside of it, but it can be as big and complex as necessary.

EDIT: To clarify the capabilities of this clock: A clock that meets my specifications that was sent on a journey should display the same time as a clock left on Earth when it is returned to Earth.

Further EDIT: This clock should match a clock left on Earth at all times and places. If the starship travelers want to celebrate Christmas on the same day as their families on Earth they should be able to using this clock.

Comment: I'm not a temporal scientist, but I would think that if a system in reference frame A isn't told what time it is in reference frame B, it can't accurately tell you what time it is in reference frame B.

Comment: What are the limits of your "observe the universe outside of it" rule?

Comment: @Frostfyre The primary purpose of the rule was so that the clock could not observe external phenomena to determine its speed or position or the passage of time. The clock is capable of measuring things happening to itself though. It can have an accelerometer as part of its mechanism.

Comment: @MikeNichols Can you clarify if by "continue to display the time on Earth" you mean "match a clock left on Earth"? Under a very captious interpretation, as RBarryYoung says, "there is no such thing as the current time on earth". I assumed you just were asking for the clock on the ship to match the clocks on Earth when they can be compared again.

Comment: @Samuel A clock that meets my specifications that was sent on a journey should display the same time as a clock left on Earth when it is returned to Earth.

Comment: this unique clock is impossible using "non-exotic matter", the rest is homework for the readers!

Comment: As this is a substantial change/clarification, you should add it to your question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I don't feel like it is a substantial clarification. In the question I said, "the clock would continue to display the time on Earth". I think it follows that if the clock were to return to Earth it would still "continue to display the time on Earth" and therefore would match a clock left on Earth. But I'll go ahead and edit the question anyways.

Comment: @MikeNichols The clarification is whether you require the clocks to match when one *is not on Earth*.  Because that's not possible.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The clocks should match at all times and in all places. I'll edit this in as well.

Comment: Ah, in that case @matt has the correct answer: it cannot be done, because according to Einstein, there's no such thing as "*the current time on Earth*" when you are not on Earth.  See the extensive discussions below. Even if it were receiving a signal from the clock on Earth, it could not tell how much time had elapsed since it was sent.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm not well versed in relativity (hence the question), but by your logic does that mean there is no such thing as the current time in France when you are not in France? Or the current time on my left wrist watch when I'm comparing it to my right wrist watch? If I wave my arms around then they are in slightly different reference frames right? No two clocks can ever share the exact same frame of reference, so can any two clocks ever match perfectly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The minimum degree of uncertainty is related to how far apart the clocks are and for how long they've been apart without communication.  Generally it is approximate/proportional to their distance divided by the speed of light.

Comment: @MikeNichols It really comes down to whether you want a physicist solution or an engineering solution. Engineering can provide you with the results you're asking for, a physicist will tell you that technically you're not getting the real thing you specifically asked for though the difference can't be measured.

Comment: *"Can you build a relativistic clock?"* Yes, but it'll take forever.  Just build a time machine and come get it at the end of time when I'm done.

Comment: @MikeNichols Re: the further edit, there is no way to actually see if the clocks are the same when in different reference frames, all you can ask for is that the clocks match when they're together again. If you can return at any time and have the clocks match, then what is the difference? It would be the same as setting your watch in sync with someone else who goes to another room, you both do a little dance when the watches read noon, and then they return to make sure the watches are still in sync. It can't be *known* that the events were synchronized, but it's certainly plenty satisfying.

Answer (score 23):

**No.**

In General (and indeed Special) Relativity, there is actually no such thing as "the time on Earth" from the point of view of a distant observer. There is also no such thing as "the place it was set".

Relativistically speaking, the only things that make sense are *events* - which in non-relativistic terms, can be thought of as a combination of a time and a place together. The relationship between events depends on whether they are *timelike*, *spacelike* or *null* separated:

- Two events are timelike separated if a massive object (such as a spaceship) can get from one event to the other without resorting to exotic things like wormholes or warp drive.
- Two events are null separated events if only a massless particle (e.g. a photon) can get from one to the other.
- Two spacelike separated events can't be experienced by the same particle or object even if it can travel at the speed of light. You can't send a signal between two spacelike separated events.

A pair of timelike or null separated events always happen in a particular order, and everyone agrees on what order they happen in. So everyone can agree that event A happens before event B, no matter where they are or how fast they are going.

However, people might disagree on the order in which two spacelike events happen. In fact, it doesn't really make sense to say that event A happens 'before' event B if they are spacelike separated.

This means that if you leave Earth in a spaceship tomorrow, and you want a clock that tells you what the time is on Earth, you are out of luck! The 'time on Earth now' isn't a well defined concept. What you could potentially do is have a clock that tells you, for example, what the earliest time it could be on Earth when a signal you emit reaches home: the sending and receiving events are null separated, so you don't have a problem. You could also have a clock that tells you the time on Earth that you would observe if you looked back at a clock on Earth with an enormous telescope.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for a shipboard-clock that will, anytime the ship returns, match a clock left on Earth. Are you saying that is not possible?

Comment: Without communication or observation of Earth, yes. There's no saying what has happened on Earth in the meantime: if a large black hole has passed very close by, then clocks on Earth will be slowed to a degree that the shipboard clock can't predict.

Comment: Ok, so actually you mean *yes, they're possible, but not perfectly to the attosecond in the case of unpredicted events*?

Comment: Well, to my mind 'not perfectly' means 'no'. And it may be considerably more than an attosecond if the black hole hangs around for a long time. I'm also not sure what you mean by 'unpredicted events'. No event is exactly predictable.

Comment: I think if you assume some context: a ship that starts here and roams where reachable (e.g. no black holes nearby) and the whole ship is allowed to be "the clock", just no observations of the stars our outside sources, it can be approximated for use as a fall-back. Especially if you only need to use it between outside sightings, not forever since launch.

Comment: @matt I certainly appreciate the scientific basis of your answer, but your follow up seems captious. A clock travelling at relativistic speeds which can be adjusted to match one left on Earth to within a few tens of milliseconds would certainly satisfy as a satisfactory solution for most people, don't you think? Unpredictable means it can't be predicted, which is exactly what you just said would cause the error: "...to a degree that the shipboard clock can't predict."

Comment: @Samuel: No, the OP did not ask for "*a shipboard-clock that will, anytime the ship returns, match a clock left on Earth*".  They very clearly and specifically asked for a clock that would read the time on Earth, and as matt indicate this is not possible because *there is no such thing as the current time on earth*.

Comment: @RBarryYoung They very clearly and specifically asked for something that doesn't exist? Perhaps what the OP means by "continue to display the time on Earth" is "match a clock left on Earth". Does that seem too far fetched? Perhaps we should ask.

Comment: @Samueal yes, they asked if something that cannot exist could exist.  It can't.  And even "match a clock left on earth" technically only has meaning if you are *on* earth.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You quoted me when I wrote "anytime the ship returns". That means to Earth. Would you say GPS satellites don't have clocks that match clocks on Earth? Did we adjust them for nothing?

Comment: @Samuel You can never know whether any two separate clocks match "exactly" because under relativity there is no such thing as simultaneity for objects separated by distance.  It is, however, possible to get within a certain *range* of accuracy, dependent on the distance and elapsed time.  For satellites in low earth orbit that range is small and the satellites use GR corrections for their orbit along with periodic re-synchonization with ground clocks to stay within that range.  For a ship light-years away visiting giant stars, this range is very large & worse, no re-synchronization is allowed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Well, at this point the OP has, as I assumed, asked for a clock which matches one left on Earth. The clock can be any complexity and size, there aren't any specific laws of the Universe barring the proper adjustment of this clock, so it is possible to do.

Comment: This answer is based on an incorrect interpretation of the question. The OP wants a clock that matches a clock left on Earth, not this non-existent "time on Earth".

Comment: @Samuel, the OP has clarified that they are only requiring the clocks to match when returned to earth.  This takes care of the simultaneity problem, but does not address the other reasons it cannot be done.  And it's not so much the *laws of the universe* barring this hypothesized clock from working as it is the rules of the question: if you cannot observe the universe around you, then you cannot tell how your temporal gradient might be changing.

Comment: Personally, I would use the term "lightlike separated" instead of "null separated," which sounds like it means "not separated" (and we don't want to get into a discussion of proper time just yet).  It also meshes better with the term "lightlike path/curve."

Comment: @Samuel Oops, now the OP has *re*-clarified, they want the clock to match the clock on earth *all the time*, even when it's separated.  And according to Einstein, that's not possible because there's no such thing as the "*current time somewhere else*".

Comment: This is the correct answer for one reason - we cannot know on the spaceship what events have happened on the Earth.  We regularly correct our clocks on Earth - leap seconds.  On the space ship we cannot know (without communication) when that happens.  Nor can we communicate to ask about other time altering events.  While the difference between the time zone on Earth and the clock on the spaceship that accounts for gravity and acceleration (Samuel's answer) might be only seconds it still is not 'exactly' the same time.  I suspect though that it is 'close enough' for a plot line.

Comment: @TracyCramer There have been 24 leap seconds in the last 42 years. It seems a fairly acceptable error. Besides, it's not an error due to relativity, so doesn't really apply to this question.

Comment: @TracyCramer I only argue that is is not the correct answer. This answer doesn't say a clock can get close, it flat out says it's not possible, as if "time on Earth" were *non-existent* and can not even be approximated with any degree of accuracy. Yet, you apparently agree that it could be possible to some degree of accuracy, which seems to contradict your statement of this being the correct answer.

Comment: This answer is good, but it might be improved if the initial statement of "no such thing as the time on Earth" was supported with a link or two about the [relativity of simultaneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity), which explicitly says that what event on a distant observer's worldline is simultaneous with a given date on Earth depends on one's choice of [reference frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference), with all frames being equally valid physically.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes.**

Though it's not *immune*, it's just *informed*. Luckily you have no limit on complexity or size, because it's not going to be simple or small. This isn't any kind of shielding, the time is simply adjusted given proper inputs. In the same way we would be able to calculate the effects from time dilation given the proper information about the system, like acceleration and gravity for each frame of reference, we could do that in 'real time' for a clock. If the clock is provided (or internally measures) the requisite information, it can calculate, within the precision of the information it's given, the time in a different reference frame.

EDIT:
BrettFromLA brings up a good point, intentionally or not, that measuring gravity and acceleration will muss with the velocity (with respect to Earth) measurements. The velocity would normally be measured by integrating the ship's acceleration with respect to time, but the acceleration due to gravity would be superimposed on those measurements. To account for that, careful measurement of all forces acting on the ship would be required. By tracking engine output, micrometeor impacts, radiation, etc; the acceleration adding to the velocity with respect to Earth's reference frame could be measured. In this way the clock, being allowed any size or complexity, could be considered as a gaussian surface around the entire ship. The measurements required would be only forces acting on the ship/clock. Clearly this is more complex than simply looking at an external reference, but it is still possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25177/discussion-on-answer-by-samuel-can-you-build-a-relativistic-clock).

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a spaceship that constantly maintains a line of sight to our solar system, you could monitor the red/blue shift of our sun, as seen from your ship. From that you can infer what kind of time dilation you are experiencing with regards to the Earth and correct the clock's time as you go along.

This gives you the time of our solar system, as it appears to you. Then add to that time a year for every light-year that you have travelled.

EDIT: I'll try to briefly explain red/blue shifting, because probably not everybody is familiar with these terms. The speed of light is constant, so when you move towards/away from an object, the light coming from it to you does not seem to change its speed relative to you. But it seems to change its wavelength in a predictable way in relation to the relative speed. When you split light coming from a star into a spectrum (like a prism splits it into a rainbow), there are gaps in the spectrum, which are characteristic of every star. By tracking how these gaps move towards the red or blue end of the spectrum, you can find out how much the light has shifted.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. We appreciate to have references to answer, to improve their quality. Not everyone is familiar, with, say the red/blue shift.

Comment: That would count as observing the universe.

Answer (score 2):

Would you be happy with something pseudo-scientific?

**Quantum entangled oscillator**

Similarly to how a quartz crystal's oscillation will provide a time signal for a modern watch, you could have some kind of quantum particle suspended in a field that causes it to oscillate at a very well-defined frequency.

Then you'd need some mechanism to entangle a 'receiver' with the oscillating particle. This means that measuring the state of the 'receiver' gives you the state of the oscillator.

Entanglement seems to allow instantaneous communication - meaning that the 'receiver' will oscillate at the same observed frequency as on Earth - meaning, it will get faster as the ship accelerates away from Earth. (although, I don't remember reading anything involving entanglement and accelerating frames of reference).

It might even be possible to have multiple entanglements.

This is actually probably not at all different to various ansible mechanisms that have appeared in other works.

Comment: Quantum entanglement doesn't violate relativity - your implied understanding (and use) of it does, though. Sure, you could postulate for the sake of the story that entanglement really does work that way (a ton of sci-fi does, of course), but then you'd have to explain why you still get relativistic effects *without* the limit of the speed of light. Most sci-fi gets around it by throwing relativity out entirely - until you get to that one novel/episode where they use relativistic time-dilation, of course :D

Comment: http://www.gizmag.com/quantum-entanglement-speed-10000-faster-light/26587/ < seems to imply that entanglement isn't limited to the speed of light

Comment: Yup, and it's wrong. It's not all that surprising, science tends to take a *lot* of time to propagate. It isn't all that long ago that this was still taught in schools, even though we've known the answer for *decades*. The whole argument basically boils down to "and now this transfers the information without violating relativity" - without showing any consistent way of how this could ever work. Really, the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum physics (the "spooky action at distance"-based one :)) violates so many of the basic laws it's incredible it *ever* got traction. Elan vital again :)

Comment: Quantum entanglement does *not* transfer *information* faster than the speed of light.  Nothing that happens to the first particle, *after* entanglement is infer-able from the second through entanglement or it's collapse. The two particles have a paired state that cannot be manipulated without collapsing it.

Answer (score 1):

### A Broken Clock and a Black Hole

Take a clock and throw out the battery. Now throw a black hole at the earth. Now time on earth is frozen, as [time does not pass in a black hole](http://www.phys.vt.edu/~jhs/faq/blackholes.html#q2). The time on the clock will match the time on earth.

This solution, though it may require a lot of mass, is not very complicated. I suppose the criteria "If the starship travelers want to celebrate Christmas on the same day as their families on Earth they should be able to using this clock" is fulfilled [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) now.